# String List array search for a string

Tags: android, string, search, arraylist

Im having problems with searching through a list array trying to find certain string and then storing that string into a variable called name

```
            private List<String> listview_array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> listview_array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> listview_array3 = new ArrayList<String>();

                    String name1 = null;

    if(listview_array1.contains("The")) {


        //assign value to name1     

        System.out.println(name1);
    }
```

Comment: Okay so what is the problem your actually having?

Comment: You want to assign name1 with the value 'The' ?

Comment: no i want to assign whichever position it found "The" to name1

Comment: But position is index (integer) and name1 is String. Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry i'm not very good at explaining things, say for example if the string contains "The Masters" for instance and im just checking for "The". How could I assign "The Masters" to the variable name1 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is your friend.  In general the first line of any question of how do I use a class is look up it's docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

As to your question you will want the indexof method.  Details on the page above.